# How can I sort my different height same width thumbnail like that?

Tags: jquery, image, sorting, thumbnails

I have images with same width but different heights... I have seen that before but i ca't remember where i see... I want to sort my thumbnails like above. 
[alt text http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/9730/thumbnailjt.jpg](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/9730/thumbnailjt.jpg)

so let the fight begin :)

Comment: Uh.... what? You have a collection of items and you want to loop through their heights, re-order them so that they are more or less the same height, and then arrange them into columns? Is that more correct?

Comment: Yep. The images have same width but different heigths. But give column with variable will be better. so not neccessary to calculate columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short example how you can sort elements and then append them to other div.

```js
// returns elements sorted by height
$('.elementsToSort').sort(function (a, b) {
   return $(a).height() > $(b).height() ? 1 : -1;  
});

// or loop over results and append them to another placeholder
$('.elementsToSort').children().each(function(){

    $smallest = $('.elementsToSort').sort(function (a, b) {
           return $(a).height() > $(b).height() ? 1 : -1;  
    }).first();
    $('.placeHolder').append($smallest);
})
```